# Change the phrase on the blank page of VIM

Tags: vim

I have done a customization of vim and I would like to share it with my colleagues. some changes have been made to the command system and I would like to show them on the initial homepage (in case you open vim without selecting a file). I wanna change the

```
             VIM - Vi IMproved
              version 7.4.629
           by Bram Moolenaar et al.
      Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
  Vim is open source and freely distributable
       Help poor children in Uganda!
type  :help iccf<Enter>       for information
type  :q<Enter>               to exit
type  :help<Enter>  or  <F1>  for on-line help
type  :help version7<Enter>   for version info
```

can someone kindly help me? I can't find any information about this text.

Comment: There is a Vi and Vim StackExchange at vi.stackexchange.com, you would probably be best off asking there. I don't think you can actually *replace* the text short of rebuilding Vim but you could probably do something on `VimEnter` when no buffer is loaded or when `argc() == 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That text, described under `:h :intro`, can only be changed by changing the [source](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/9acf2d8be93f3b50607279e7f3484b019675d0a7/src/version.c#L9232) except for the "Modified by" bit that can be changed with the `--with-modified-by` `configure` argument or the `MODIFIED_BY` `define`. Whatever you do to change the intro message must be done at build time, as its content is **not** settable/gettable at runtime.

As mentioned in the comments, you might be able to show *some* information to your colleagues at startup with an autocommand on `VimEnter` if Vim was started without a filename:

```
function! DoSomethingIfNoArgs()
    if argc() == 0
        echomsg 'look ma, no file'
    endif
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call DoSomethingIfNoArgs()
```

But, since the intro message is off-limits at runtime, you would still have to decide *how* to show that info:

- `:echo` a list of features,
- show the content of a file in a preview window,
- use a popup window,
- play an audio clip,
- something else?

which is another topic entirely.

Answer (score 0):

There are plug-ins such as [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) and [dashboard-nvim](https://github.com/glepnir/dashboard-nvim) which allow you to replace the default Vim intro with some text that you can define yourself. With the added benefit that they can also present a menu showing recently edited files, or recently defined marks, popular places to start, etc. that might give you some useful actions to consider, when opening Vim without loading a file right away...